# Html white list in c#

Tags: c#, html, regex, whitelist, blacklist

Spent about 30 minutes or so on SO looking for a definitive solution to this problem.

This question seems to have been asked a lot of times but...

- Most solutions use regular expressions.
- There are a lot of posts saying that regular expresions should not be used to process html.
- There are lots of answers simply giving a link to the HTMLAgilityPack (on Codeplex) but no real examples of how to use this pack to meet the stated requirements.

So I am looking for the best solution to meet the following requirements.

- I want to provide an *allowed* list of HTML tags.
- Any tags not in the allowed list should be removed along with their attributes and contents.
- Any tags in the allowed list should be preserved with attributes and contents.
- The solution should cope with differnet localisations - it is possible users using languages and character sets other than those used in English will be used.
- [Added] The solution should handle text such as a forum post as opposed to a full html page - so tags such as b u i etc would be allowed but script div etc are not allowed and should be removed.

I am looking for a C# solution and *if* its best to use a RegEx then I am happy to do so. If there is an existing library that can do this I am also happy to use them. I would appreciate some example code where possible.

I am looking for a definitive and tried and tested method of solving this problem as opposed to extensive debate + closed posts etc :) :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we talking about a valid HTML document or are we talking about a piece of text that contains some HTML tags, e.g. a forum post?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - good point I will update the question.

Comment: For a forum you might want to use BBCode and use a converter to HTML. Then, you can simply replace all <s and >s and you don't have the risk to forget blocking some uncommon tags.

Comment: For this project its more like a blog - I want the user to be able to use defined tags which will include divs and also a pre-selected list of class names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing the HTML. Then you can work with the elements the way you like and write it back to HTML again.

Comment: Please provide an example of how this meets my requirements. The CodePlex examples for the HTML Agility Pack are sparse.

Comment: Well - every application is unique. Thus, the documentation on the HTML Agility Pack won't include an example on how to exactly solve *your* problem. However, you can use the HTML Agility Pack to recursively iterate over all nodes ("tags") in the HTML document and remove the onse you don't want to have.

Comment: Sounds interesting - I'll test it and report back. Do you have a snippet of how to get all of the tags?

Comment: Try 'doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*")' to select all nodes in an HtmlDocument (uses XPath: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp ); see also: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples